# Shibboleth Configuration with ADFS 3.0 at the IDP sever

Tags: shibboleth

We are very (very) new to shibboleth and we are using ADFS3.0 in our IDP server and for the Shibboleth authentication. The issue that I am facing is even though the IDP is authenticating my request I don't see any user information in my request headers or in my server variables.

The question is what configuration should I have to adjust to get this information in my request.

Am I missing to add any configuration settings in my shibboleth2.xml or in the attrribute-map.xml in the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a start, when configuring a Relying Party (in this case your Shibboleth SP) in ADFS, you will need to configure claims to be issued.

For a start, perhaps configure your ADFS server to send the UserPrincipalName as a Name ID claim. You can use the "Send LDAP Attributes as Claim" template under "Issuance Transform Rules" in your ADFS. Then check again and see if it appear in your server variable.